What does "Warning Output Binary Stream-Stream Closed" mean in Pamguard?
I'm running files through click detectors in Pamguard version 2.02.14. In the upper corner of the display, there is an error saying "What does "Warning Output Binary Stream-Stream Closed." Does anyone know what this means? Are my binary files not writing correctly?


Are you seeing binary files generated? I've had red warnings sort of similar to this if my connection to the server (over VPN) gets interrupted. It looks like things are still working but they aren't. No idea if that is what is going on here but maybe a hint to investigate

This is a rather terse and cryptic warning, and not straightforward to diagnose without more information on your configuration, setup, and a good understanding of internal processes of PAMGuard (and maybe also a debugger).
If you're not experiencing any other issues, then it's probably safe to ignore (after all it's a warning, not an error).
If you are experiencing issues, for example an inability to load required binary files in Viewer mode or in other software, then probably time to file a bug-report with the PAMGuard developers.
